# how to download docx,pdf and xls files that are stored as blob in oracle

Tags: java, maven, struct, blob

```
    if (fileData != null && fileName != null) {
        String fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length());
        if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("doc")){
            generateOutput(response,"application/msword",fileData,fileName);
        } else if(fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("docx")){
            generateOutput(response,"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",fileData,fileName);
        } else if (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
            generateOutput(response,"application/pdf",fileData,fileName);
        } else if ((fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) || (fileType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx"))) {
            generateExcelOutput(response,fileData,fileName);
        } else {

        }
    }
```

I have created a condition based on the extension of file am setting set content type when I try to download the files pdf always comes as empty and Docx file as always corrupted I can view the content in word file but have to copy the content to newer file, not the file that got downloaded

```
private void generateOutput(HttpServletResponse response, String mimeType, byte[] fileData, String fileName)
throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    response.setHeader("charset", "iso-8859-1");
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength(fileData.length);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

do we have any maven POC to download Pdf and Docx files I have created a custom method to download excel files using CSVReader may be something like that one for Pdf and Docx

Comment: Do you get the exact bytes you expect?

Comment: am getting blob by query then translate to byte file

Comment: Yes.  How are the bytes the client receives different from what you expect them to be?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how to check bytes i recieve from blob column are correct is there a way am not sure but  the file i upload and download are different i upload file with content that editable but when i download file is corrupted

Comment: Yes.  Figuring out where the original bytes, the ones in the database and the downloaded bytes are different is crucial for analysis.  You will need to do some work now.